Identify an episode of an old TV show where a man has to stop a plane from crashing into his house
I have this memory of an episode of a show I watched with my dad when I was a kid in the 90s. It very well could have been an older show than that, though. I don't remember whether it was in color. It must have been a show like the Twilight Zone or Outer Limits, where the episodes are stand-alone stories.
I remember it was about a man who, I think, started seeing ghosts of children. I remember torn up toys, a teddy bear. Mostly I remember that it was uncomfortable and sad to watch. The man was to stop a plane from crashing into his house, I think. The children were like, victims of the plane crash that hadn't happened yet, trying to warn him. Something along those lines. I'm fairly certain it ends with him preventing the plane crash and everything going back to normal.
Does anybody recognize this? 

You are sure it's not Donnie Darko?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donnie_Darko

Sounds like the Amazing Stories episode You Gotta Believe Me from 1986 with Charles Durning.

Convinced that his vivid nightmare of a Boeing 747 crashing into his house is a horrific premonition, Earl Sweet desperately tries to alter fate.

In his dream he sees the ghosts of the passengers, some of which are kids, and a torn teddybear (which features prominently throughout the episode). The man then frantically rushes to the airport, finds the actual flight and tries to prevent the disaster, ultimately succeeding. The story was written by Steven Spielberg. Can't find clips, but here's the man when he reaches the airport:


The plane had no phalanges.. right?

This has to be it. Thanks!
